# How to compare part of string against large database in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

1. I've a mysql table that has a column of domain names (around 100k rows)

Example :

```
ID    Domain_Name
 1    AnotherOlataxi.xom
 2    goodlolita.com
```

2. I've few more tables that contains words from many different languages like English words, french words etc.

Example:

```
ID    Language   Word 
1     en         good
2     en         taxi
3     fr         ola
```

I want to compare each domain with the languages table and find words and language.

Example : 
I should get a list of words and languages.
If I run the domain anotherolataxi.com ,  it should return like

```
Array(
 'another'=>'en',
 'ola'   => 'fr',
 'taxi' =>'en'
)
```

How can I get this result and how to compare these large tables without compromising perfomance?

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that the matching can only be done purely on a character matching basis, whether the found word is truly within the domain name, that cannot be decided fully. For example, AnotherOlataxi also contains the word "hero" if I look at the sequence of characters only. If you have that word within your words list, then you will have a match, even though the word is not really there.

Comment: Yes. that's a valid point. But is there a way to slice a part of staring like the first matching word will be "another". So it will be removed from the string and then the "OlaTaxi" will be there

Comment: It's difficult. let's assume that "ano" is a valid word in a language. How do you determine if you should match on "ano" first and remove that from the domain name, or go with "another"?

Comment: One more issue you will face is when you have the same word in multiple languages. They may be pronounced differently, may mean completely different things, but their spelling is the same. For example, "ola" is not just a French word, but Spanish as well. How do you decide which language to pick for a word in a domain name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `like`.  It won't be efficient, but it does do what you want:

```
select d.*, w.*
from domains d join
     words w
     on d.domain_name like concat('%', w.word, '%');
```

For a single domain, the performance should not be too bad.  You can add a `where` clause:

```
where d.id = 1
```

for instance.